# HttpsURLConnection request bypassing the Global proxy in Android

Tags: android, kotlin, proxy, httpconnection, httpsurlconnection

We have configured the **global proxy** with a network in an Android device, and it needs a certificate to execute any request to the server.

When I make a request using OkHttpClinet as below

```
 val request = Request.Builder().url(url).build()
            val client = OkHttpClient()
            client.newCall(request = request).enqueue(object : Callback {
                override fun onFailure(call: Call, e: IOException) {
                  
                }

                override fun onResponse(call: Call, response: Response) {
                  
                }
            })
```

**It's working as expected with OkHttpClinet if a certificate is not installed it throws the below exception if the certificate is installed it will execute the request successfully.**

```
java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
```

when we make the same request using HttpsURLConnection as below

```
val urlConnection: HttpsURLConnection
               
                val url = URL(url)
                urlConnection = url.openConnection() as HttpsURLConnection
                val responseCode = urlConnection.responseCode
```

**It's not working as expected with HttpsURLConnection, it always gets executed successfully without checking certificate is installed or not**

if we specify proxy like   `val proxy = Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, InetSocketAddress(proxyHost, proxyPort)) urlConnection = url.openConnection(proxy ) as HttpsURLConnection`

it's working as expected, but don't want to set the proxy locally with a request, **how can we use HttpsURLConnection to use a global proxy with a certificate?**

**Note** Both requests are executed from the same application with the same network. networkSecurityConfig is already allowing to access the system and user-installed certificate.